# missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++

I have a cpp file that contains the following:

```
char const* types[] = { "char", "short", "int", "long", "float", "double", "void"};
std::set<std::string> ReservedWords;
ReservedWords.insert(std::begin(types),std::end(types));
```

this gives an error `missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

I have read that you can't write statements in a global scope, is this the case here ?

I don't completely understand the rule, and would like to know where its best to put this code ? (header file, inside a function etc...)

Comment: You've answered you own question, you can't have non-declaration statements at global scope. You need to put most of your code in functions.

Comment: @CharlesBailey so in global scope i can only declare a variable but can't initialize it ? so should i initialize it in the constructor ?

Comment: No, you can initialize variables at global scope, you just can't have random statements that aren't a declaration at global scope.

Comment: @CharlesBailey so the third line is the problem...

Comment: @Michael calling `std::set<std::string>::insert()` is not an initialization, so the third line looks like a problem.

Comment: Surely the compiler _tells_ you which line is the problem? Why did you ignore the line number in the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char const* types[] = { "char", "short", "int", "long", "float", "double", "void"};
std::set<std::string> ReservedWords;
ReservedWords.insert(std::begin(types),std::end(types));
```

The first two lines here are declarations because they declare variables (`types` and `ReservedWords`). The third line is not a declaration, it's just an expression statement so it's not legal for it to appear outside a function.

You could do something like:

```
char const* types[] = { "char", "short", "int", "long", "float", "double", "void"};
std::set<std::string> MakeReservedWords() {
    std::set<std::string> tmp;
    tmp.insert(std::begin(types), std::end(types));
    return tmp;
}

std::set<std::string> ReservedWords(MakeReservedWords());
```

Given that you are using C++11 you should be able to do this:

```
std::set<std::string> ReservedWords { "char", "short", "int", "long", "float", "double", "void"};
```

If your compiler doesn't support this part of C++11 you will have to settle for something like this (as suggested by @juanchopanza):

```
char const* types[] = { "char", "short", "int", "long", "float", "double", "void"};
std::set<std::string> ReservedWords(std::begin(types), std::end(types));
```

Comment: sometimes reading the compiler errors just confuses me and makes me ignore my common sense...

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `std::set`'s two-iterator constructor?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, I was just exhibiting a way of using an initialization using `insert`.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested last and the compiler gives `error C2470: ReservedWords : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body`

Comment: @Michael: I assumed that you were using C++11 because of your use of `std::begin` and `std::end`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: i'm not sure how to find out. but i'm using default project settings in visual studio 2011

Answer (score 2):

First, not that `std::begin` and `std::end` are C++11, so are you sure you have a compatible compiler and that you're compiling with C++11 support?

I don't believe this is *the* error though. Are you including:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
```

?

Comment: yes, i have included all of them. also, these lines are written in the cpp file outside the scope of any function

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when you don't include the correct files. Make sure to add 
`#include <string.h>`

And yes, you must remove this line from global scope:

```
ReservedWords.insert(std::begin(types),std::end(types));
```

Try putting it in the main function.